# My (windows 10) pc wakes up every hour for 2 minutes how do I stop that?

Tags: windows-10, sleep

I think the question speaks for itself?

some extract from

```
powercfg /SLEEPSTUDY
```

[image]

Why does it do that and how do I stop it?

```
powercfg /WAKETIMERS

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /WAKETIMERS
Timer set by [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (SystemEventsBroker) expires at 17:55:30 on 8-1-2018.
  Reason: De geplande taak NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot wordt uitgevoerd, waarmee het inschakelen van de computer wordt aangevraagd.
```

The dutch text says: The planned task NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot is being executed, with which the power on of the computer is requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.howtogeek.com/122954/how-to-prevent-your-computer-from-waking-up-accidentally/

That is a very detailed article on how to detect, then prevent any/all wake timers from turning on your PC, but here's a short rundown on 1 of the options that might take care of your situation:

> Go to your Power Options,
>   Click "Change plan settings",
>   Click "Change advanced power settings",
>   Expand "Sleep",
>   Expand "Allow Wake Timers",
>   Click the option and select "Disable"

This might only take care of some of your issue, so go through all the other options as a safeguard for all options.  As the article mentions, it might be your "mouse, keyboard, or network adapter or events like wake timers or automatic maintenance".

What I suggested above, on second thought, might disable wake on keyboard or mouse click, so that might be too much for what you want.  You'll have to do some testing, since I don't have that ability right now.

Comment: Completely disabling waking up wasn't an option but on the page you reference, more precisely "Prevent Automatic Maintenance From Waking Your PC" did the trick, thanks for your answer

Comment: As many options as were on that page, I figured *something* would work.  I'm glad it did!

Answer (score 1):

---

Install pstools
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools

Extract the tool package

Open cmd with admin rights

Use either psexec (32 bit system) or psexec64 (64 bit system)

psexec64 cmd.exe

In the new cmd window run

SCHTASKS /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot" /DISABLE

Results in

INFO: Scheduled task "Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot" has already been disabled.
SUCCESS: The parameters of scheduled task "Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot" have been changed.

Also run this to disable access to above setting

icacls "%WINDIR%\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot" /inheritance:r /deny "Everyone:F" /deny "SYSTEM:F" /deny "Local Service:F" /deny "Administrators:F"

Results in

processed file: C:\WINDOWS\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

You can check the Task Scheduler (with admin rights) for Reboot task; it is disabled and access is denied. Also check that the Schedule Scan and USO_Broker_Display tasks have "Wake the computer to run this task" unchecked in "Conditions" tab.

Done! And you again own your own computer which you paid for :) FU MS. Thanks to DebayanGupta at

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/administrator-account-not-allowed-to-disable

---

Answer (score 0):

PSexec didn't work for me because access denied. In such case what you can do is:
open notepad and type

```
schtasks /tn "Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Universal Orchestrator Start" /change /disable > c:\temp\res.txt 2>&1
```

save it as something like c:\temp\disableit.cmd

open task scheduler, create new task, set action to run the above created file

set task to run under SYSTEM

run task and check the logfile c:\temp\res.txt.
It should say

SUCCESS: The parameters of scheduled task "Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Universal Orchestrator Start" have been changed.